# C# Sorting List based on a condition

Tags: c#

I want to sort a list based on a pattern from and to

```
public class Group
{         
    public string From {get;set;}
    public string To { get; set; }
}
```

I have a list of group populated from DB, which is not populated in order

```
List<Group> myGroup = new List<Group>();
```

My Group contains items in order below:

```
Fr  To
534-527
111-534
527-535
534-111
527-534
```

It should be Re-Arranged in the below order

```
527-534
534-111
111-534
534-527
527-535
```

```
    public List<Group> SortRepHistoryList(List<Group> group)
    {
        LinkedList<Group> sortedList = new LinkedList<Group>();

        var tempFrom = group.Select(t => t.From).ToList();
        Group lastItem = group.FirstOrDefault(g => !tempFrom.Contain(g.To));

        sortedList.AddLast(lastItem);
        group.Remove(lastItem);

        while (group.Any())
        {
            var prev = group.Where(g => g.To.Equals(lastItem.From));
            if (null == prev)
            {
                return sortedList.ToList();
            }

            else if (prev.Count() == 1)
            {
                sortedList.AddFirst(prev.First());
                lastItem = prev.First();
                group.Remove(lastItem);
            }
            else if (prev.Count() > 1)
            {

            }
        }
        return sortedList.ToList();
    }
```

This represents the data of Change History from one code to other code, for example, the initial code is 527 which is modified to 534 on one instance, again 534 modified to 111, again 111 modified to 534, again 534 modified to 527, again 527 modified to 535, so here the latest code is 535 and the oldest value is 527 ( remember there wont be any duplicates here )

Is there is way to handle this?

Comment: How are we meant to know the first "534-X" value should be "534-111" instead of "534-527"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you described can be formulated as visiting all the nodes in the directed graph with loops. It is not hm... sorting.

So let's say that the node has a number associated with it. And there is an edge from one node to another. The list of visiting edges in the order of visiting is the output.

This link can be of interest to you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm